# How to use grep in csh script

Tags: shell, csh

Below is a simple csh script I wrote. But the set does not work. Can anyone please help me with the error.

```
#!/bin/csh
echo "hello"
set ans ='grep -r hello ./'
echo ans
```

Tried back quotes still not working:

```
   #!/bin/csh
echo "hello"
set ans =`grep -r hello .`
echo $ans
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of a variable you have to add a `$` to the beginning:

```
echo $ans
```

Furthermore you should remove the space in front of the `=` sign:

```
set ans=`grep -r hello .`
```

Comment: I was going to edit my post for this. With both changes you should be good.

Comment: @ArlaudAgbePierre: Yes, I think that's true.

Comment: @Programmer: From the `csh` manpage: *Note also that '=' can be adjacent to both name and word or separated from both by whitespace, but cannot be adjacent to only one or the other.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to use backquotes `` and not simplequotes ''.

Also variables are instanciated without a dollar but you need to access them like `$ans`

```
#!/bin/csh
echo "hello"
set ans =`grep -r hello .`
echo $ans
```

Comment: see edit please. not sure if you the ans is correcdt

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that too… Thank god I'm not coding in CSH any more. Good luck with your future projects!